# Trouble while trying to convert .pb to .nn using tensorfow_to_barracuda.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, unity-game-engine, neural-network, protocol-buffers

I am getting the following error

```
Converting C:\Users\qwerty\Documents\saved_model.pb to output.nn
Sorting model, may take a while.... Done!
IGNORED: GatherV2 unknown layer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow_to_barracuda.py", line 26, in <module>
    tf2bc.convert(args.source_file, args.target_file, args.trim_unused_by_output, args)
  File "C:\Repos\ml-agents\ml-agents\mlagents\trainers\tensorflow_to_barracuda.py", line 1552, in convert
    i_model, args
  File "C:\Repos\ml-agents\ml-agents\mlagents\trainers\tensorflow_to_barracuda.py", line 1377, in process_model
    process_layer(n, o_context, args)
  File "C:\Repos\ml-agents\ml-agents\mlagents\trainers\tensorflow_to_barracuda.py", line 1220, in process_layer
    assert all_elements_equal(input_ranks)
AssertionError
```

What would I need to do to fix this? or is there any other way to convert .pb file to .nn file to run my pretrained model in Unity Inference Engine

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tensorflow v2, you need an older `Tensorflow` version. (x<2) Even though there are patches, they may still be bugs related to `Tensorflow v2.` Uninstall it and install `1.15rc2` (for example).

Comment: actually I am using 1.14